# Derivative of question ln

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

So I have the problem

$y=(ln3)log_3x$

and one of the steps is

$y=(ln3)(1/(x * ln3))$

then the ln cancel out and I understand all of that. I'm just wondering why ln3 doesn't go to 1 if it is just a constant?

Thanks! Please fix the formatting if you can. I'm not sure how to do format division.

Comment: Can you show how you do that?

Comment: Is it to the base $3$ or base $x$?

Comment: Sorry yes I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\ln(3)\log_x(3)=\ln(3)\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(x)}$$
$$y=(\ln(3))^2(\ln(x))^{-1}$$

Derivate $y$ with respect to $x$ and use chain rule in $(\ln(x))^{-1}$. Then,

$$\dot y = \color{red}{(\ln(3))^2} \left(-(\ln(x))^{-2}x^{-1}\right)=-\color{red}{(\ln(3))^2}\frac{1}{x(\ln(x))^2}$$

$\color{red}{(\ln(3))^2}$: this multiplicative factor is a constant*, so you don't have to worry when you derive.

*Thanks, John Hughes

Comment: Perhaps better to say "this term is a multiplicative constant" (or better still, "this multiplicative factor is a constant").

Comment: Okay, I'll fix it.